# Reshaping a long array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have a long array that needs to be sliced at pre-set intervals, reshaped and put into a single nd array. For example, take a look at the code below. I tried to simplify the problem. This needs to be solved using two criteria

1. As fast as possible. So, possibly avoid the for-loop
2. Less memory usage, I am dealing with arrays that are massive. Remove `temp1` if possible

Finally, any suggestions about using better functions than `pad` or `concatenate` or anything that might make the code run faster are appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
temp = np.linspace(0, 99, 100)  # array to be reformatted
ni, nj = np.array([5, 4, 7, 2]), np.array([1, 5, 7, 13])  # shape arrays
idx = ni * nj  # [5, 20, 49, 26] indices to slice temp

# reshape the first block
x = temp[0:idx[0]].reshape((ni[0], nj[0], 1))

# pad the array for concatenate later
pad_i, pad_j = ni.max() - ni, nj.max() - nj
x = np.pad(x, [(0, pad_i[0]), (0, pad_j[0]), (0, 0)], mode='constant')

# reshape; pad; and concatenate the rest of the blocks
for i in range(1, len(idx)):
    temp1 = temp[sum(idx[0:i]):sum(idx[0:i])+idx[i]].reshape((ni[i], nj[i], 1))
    temp1 = np.pad(temp1, [(0, pad_i[i]), (0, pad_j[i]), (0, 0)], mode='constant')
    x = np.concatenate((x, temp1), axis=-1)

print(x.shape == (7, 13, 4))
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Where do the final dimensions come from?  (max(ni), max(nj), len(ni))?  It's hard to picture how original values are distributed, though the `pad` means there are a lot of 0s.  If I reproduced this I'd have to print intermediate results, and the final array, to get a clear idea of what's happening.

Comment: Repeated use of `np.concatenate` is usually a bad idea.  It makes a whole new array each time; it's not like list append which works in-place.  Collecting arrays in a list and doing one concatenate at the end is a better idea.  Alternatively make full size `x` of zeros, and assign the appropriate blocks.  `np.pad` also makes new arrays with each call.

Comment: Given the varying size of the slices, `idx`, it will be hard, if not impossible, to avoid that outer level of iteration.  The best you can do is streamline the action within that loop.

Comment: You got the logic of max dimensions correct. This is to read-in grid data file, if that helps. I think removing those functions makes sense. I will try to figure a logic that way. Thanks for the insight!